# アプリ終了しても位置情報取得したい

Tags: swift, ios, iphone, swift5

CoreLocationを使って、iphone ios13 swift5.2でフォア、バックグラウンド、アプリ終了時にユーザの位置情報をUserDefaultに保存したいです。
フォア、バックグラウンドは出来そうなのですが、アプリ終了してから位置情報取得する方法がわかりません。

Background Models> Location Update にはチェック入れました。それ以外に必要なことはあるのでしょうか。
authorizationStatus は「常に許可」の状態です。
意外に検索しても出てこなかったため途方に暮れてます。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

Appleの公式サイトに次のようなドキュメントがあります。

[Handling Location Events in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/handling_location_events_in_the_background)

必要な設定等は、再度じっくりチェックしてもらう(Info.plistの設定のことが同ページには見当たりませんが、これはiOS 13での変更点も含めて、日本語の良記事が見つかると思います)として、見ていただきたいのは表1([Table-1](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/handling_location_events_in_the_background#2865362))です。

その中で **Launches app** と言うのが、「(停止中の)アプリを起動してくれる」と言う意味になります。その欄に`Yes`が付いているのは、以下の3つのサービスのみです。

- Significant-change location service
- Visits service
- Region monitoring

あなたの言う「位置情報取得」は、おそらく通常の位置情報サービス(Standard location service)だと思うのですが、その行は **Launches app** が`No`になっているのがわかると思います。

つまり、通常の位置情報サービスを使用する限り、

**何をどう設定しても、アプリの停止中に位置情報を取得することはできません。**

---

(Visits serviceとRegion monitoringは通常の位置情報サービスとは大きくかけ離れているので)Significant-change location serviceの仕様があなたのアプリの目的に合うならば、そちらを使用するように書き換える。

それが使えそうもないならば、「そんなことはできない」と言うことを前提にアプリの機能を見直すことが必要だろうと思います。

---

なお、私のやり方が悪かっただけかもしれませんが、Significant-change location serviceをかなり前に試した時は、「うまく位置情報を拾えればラッキー」程度の精度でしか情報を拾えませんでした。実アプリに適用する前に、使い物になるかどうか、検証用のコードを作って実機で試してみることをお勧めします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。上記のアップルのサイト参考になりました。
```
```

Comment: コメントだと字数制限があるので、回答として返答させてもらいました。

Comment: @ミルク さん、返信ありがとうございます。普段だと「コメント欄に書けないような長い内容は質問文を編集して最後に追記して下さい」なんて言うことが多いんですが、今回は動作確認されたコード付きで事項回答としても大変優れたものになっているので、そのままで良いと思います。

Answer (score 1):

ありがとうございます。Handling Location Events in the Background参考になりました。
以下の内容が、サイトの情報もとにコーディングした内容です。
`willFinishLaunchingWithOptions` でlaunchOptionsを取得して、キーで
UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey　がセットされていたら、 osから終了してるアプリをコールされてる状態なので、オブジェクトを再生成。Significant-change location serviceに切り替えます。
通常時はstartUpdatingLocationを呼んで、standardで実行してます。
一応実機で試してみたら、フォア、バックグランドは大丈夫ですが、TERMINATEDの状態だとよくわかりませんでした。移動距離が数百メートだったからか取得できてる位置情報がなかったです。
「startUpdatingLocationを呼んで、standardで実行」切り替えるときに、locationManagerは生成しなおしたほうがいいのか、また生成するときに呼ぶメソッドごちにパラメータが違うのかわかりませんでした。

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        if  let _ = launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.location] {
            generateManager()
            locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()
            locationManager?.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
            return true
        }
        generateManager()
        locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager?.stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // アプリがフォアグラウンドへ移行するタイミングを通知
        locationManager?.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
        locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()

    }
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager?.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    }
    

    func generateManager() {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager?.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        locationManager?.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
        locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager?.distanceFilter = 5
        locationManager?.delegate = self
        locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }

}

extension AppDelegate : CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("error:: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let latlon = locations.last {
            let latitude = latlon.coordinate.latitude
            let longitude = latlon.coordinate.longitude
            let model = LocationModel()
            model.lat = latitude
            model.lon = longitude
            //ここで位置情報保存
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ＞「移動距離が数百メートだったからか取得できてる位置情報がなかった」ドキュメントによると500mかそれ以上と書いてあります。GPSを使わずに携帯基地局やらWiFi電波やらを使うそうなので、その辺にも依存します。コードを見る限りはそれで取れそうに思います。＞「locationManagerは生成しなおしたほうがいいのか」生成し直す必要はないはずです。パラメータの一部はサービスによっては無効なものの、無視されるだけなのでそれも問題ないと思います。他に何か気づいたことがあれば、コメントさせていただきます。